# VLSM host ip address assigning

Tags: cisco

I am trying to assign addresses in the given topology but I am having overlapping problems whenever I try to assign addresses to the routers interfaces. I have included the table of sub netting I performed for the network. I am supposed to have one pc on each switch and assign it an address and gateway. Would any body be able to help me in relation to assigning addresses to each pc? Many thanks and I would be very grateful of any help

[image: My Network]
[image: MyTable]

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

For Net A you are using a /22, but the chart shows each network is a /24.  A /22 would actually look like:

```
network id:  172.20.0.0
1st host:  172.20.0.1
last host:  172.20.3.254
broadcast:  172.20.3.255
```

What you listed is actually four different subnets:

```
172.20.0.0/24
172.20.1.0/24
172.20.2.0/24
172.20.3.0/24
```

You have a similar issue with Net B /23.  Actual /23 network:

```
network id:  172.20.4.0
1st host:  172.20.4.1
last host:  172.20.5.254
broadcast:  172.20.5.255
```

For your /30 networks everything is correct except the broadcast addresses.  Actual broadcasts:

```
172.20.7.0/30  =  172.20.7.3
172.20.7.4/30 = 172.20.7.7
172.20.7.8/30 = 172.20.7.11
```

Comment: Hi John, many thanks for the help. I made the changes to my table. In the case of the WANs, i just noticed there now that i had one of the broadcasts wrong (172.20.7.23) lol. I was juts wondering also: how do I assign ip addresses to each pc on a switch? For example, I keep getting errors when assigning ip addresses on the fast ethernet interfaces on the router for net A. The errors indicate overlapping. I would be very grateful of any help, many thanks :)